# Describe the set $\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{Q}}^1$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This is question [3.2.C](http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/FOAGdec2915public.pdf) in Vakil's Algebraic Geometry notes. I can argue that $\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{Q}}^1 = Spec(\mathbb{Q}[x])$ is essentially the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}, \overline{\mathbb{Q}}$, with two points identified if they have the same irreducible polynomial. But his descriptions of $\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{C}}^1$ and $\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{R}}^1$ have nice clean descriptions in terms of what the polynomials look like. My question is, can such an "easy" description be done for $\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{Q}}^1$?

I suspect the answer is "no," considering that by Eisenstein's criterion, there are irreducible polynomials of every degree. But since the question isn't totally clear I wanted to make sure there wasn't some nice description of *every* irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$.

Comment: No, there's no such nice description, except for polynomials of degree less than $3$.

Comment: Nope. One way of expressing your answer is that two points are identified if they lie in the same orbit under the action of the absolute Galois group. This sort of statement has nice generalizations. The real and complex numbers have very small and easy-to-understand absolute Galois groups, unlike the rationals.